Comparing people to children - is it always negative?
Do comparisons involving children always have a negative connotation in Japanese? So far, every time I've heard 子供っぽい or 子供みたい, it has meant that the person is immature or acts foolishly. At the same time, in Russian (and probably in English as well), it's possible to say that someone sleeps like a baby or is as excited as a little child without it sounding negative

As a side note, good, well-behaved children are おとなしい - etymologically, "adult-like". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%84#Japanese

You can certainly express an idea such as "innocent smile like a child" in Japanese. It would depend on which phrase you use.

子供っぽい tends to sound negative (≈ "childish"), but it's occasionally used neutrally. It doesn't carry an explicit nuance of "foolish" or "immature".
子供みたいな and 子供のような can sound negative, neutral, or positive, depending on the context (≈ "like a child" or "childlike").
ガキ臭い is always negative and derogatory.


There is also わらびしい／わらべしい（童しい）. It looks like words tend to have embedded negative or positive polarity, while multi-word phrases do not.

@YusukeMatsubara 「わらびしい」は聞いたことないです…。調べたら石川や富山あたりの方言と出てきました。

Although many expressions involving children have negative connotation, it is also common to modify certain positive characteristics, such as innocence, purity, honesty, and carefreeness, with 子供のように・子供みたいに

彼は子供みたいに無邪気だ　“He is innocent as if he were a child.”

